# Retrofit and Kotlin Post Request 400 error

Tags: android, http, retrofit2

I am trying to make a simple post request to googles dialogflow in retrofit using kotlin.  I am modeling my code off of this [site](https://medium.com/@elye.project/kotlin-and-retrofit-2-tutorial-with-working-codes-333a4422a890).  However, I keep getting 400 errors when trying to make a search so there must be something wrong with my interface creating the message body I believe.  I have working python code that does the same functionality as shown here:

```
url = "https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20170712"
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + my_key ,
  'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
}
body = {
    'lang': 'en',
    'query': 'id like to fix my wire c1000 stocks',
    'sessionId': 'me'
}
resp = r.post(url,headers=headers,data=json.dumps(body))
```

I have set this up in android studio as 3 classes:

1) Message.kt
The body of the post request

```
object Message {
    data class MsgBody(val lang: String, val query: String, val sesId: String)
}
```

2) Model.kt
The response from dialogflow

```
object Model {
    data class Response(val resp: Result)
    data class Result(val fulfillment: Fulfillment)
    data class Fulfillment(val speech: String)
}
```

3) DialogFlowService.kt
The interface that has the post request enpoint

```
interface DialogFlowService {
    @Headers(
        "Authorization: Bearer {MY API KEY}",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    )
    @POST("query")
    fun getAiMessage(@Body msg: Message.MsgBody,
                     @Query("v") v: String): Observable<Model1.Response>
    companion object {
        fun create(): DialogFlowService {

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/")
                .build()

            return retrofit.create(DialogFlowService::class.java)
        }
    }

}
```

All of this is then used in my main activity as seen below:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var disposable: Disposable? = null

    private val dialogFlowService by lazy {
        DialogFlowService.create()
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        button.setOnClickListener {
            if (editText.text.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
                sendMessage(editText.text.toString())
            }
        }
    }

    private fun sendMessage(msg: String){
        disposable = dialogFlowService.getAiMessage(Message.MsgBody("en",msg,"me"),"20170712")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { result -> textView.text = "DialogFlow says: ${result.resp.fulfillment.speech}" },
                { error -> Toast.makeText(this, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
            )
    }
    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        disposable?.dispose()
    }
}
```

I tried to follow the tutorial as close as possible and am very confused as to what I did wrong. Like I said above I think this is related to my DialogFlowService.kt file.  Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: you can use a logging interceptor to log your request and see if everything is all right.

Comment: That was very helpful thank you! I labeled sessionId as sesId and that was what was making the request bad.  Shows that I really should have been debugging better.

Comment: Yes. Logging your request in debug mode is better so that you can see what request you are sending. Similarly you can intercept a request for particular post or get and add headers to only that request. Interceptors are super useful.

Answer (score 0):

Error in post request since Model variable name sesId did not equal the actual key sessionId.  As Raghunandan said a logging interceptor is very useful